# Change Phone state to Ringing when some event occurs

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephony

I am working on an application where I have to change my Phone State to ringing when some event occurs like some number is calling on my Phone. Is that possible? I have some idea of Broadcast Receiver that will broadcast the event to my app, and then my app will make any dummy fake number call on my phone. Please give me any idea about it. Is it possible? and How to begin with it?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For Changing to ringing use TelephonyManager,AudioManager and PhoneStateListener as:

```
{
  // USE AudioManager  for Settingringing from vibration
         AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);   

         switch (am.getRingerMode()) {   
                 case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:   
                 Log.i("MyApp","NORMAL mode");
                 am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
              break;   
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add this code to make a call when some event is triggered.

```
      String Numb = "tel:" + "your number";
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(Numb));
      startActivity(intent);
```

and add permissions to your manifest for that.

```
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: @Sharmilee... I actually don't want to make a call...It is like some other number calling my phone. Will this do ?

Comment: Ok..can I make a call on my own phone programmatically ? Do you have any about this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
public class Telephone extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Context mContext;
    private Intent mIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mContext = context;
        mIntent = intent;
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)              
                 context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int events = PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE;
        tm.listen(phoneStateListener, events);
    }

    private final PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = 
                                                new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            String callState = "UNKNOWN";
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:

                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                                // DO YOUR WORK HERE

                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                          if(incomingNumber.length() >0){

                                  // incoming call
                                 // DO YOUR WORK HERE when call is received
                                 // SEND SMS HERE
                            }
                           else{
                                      // outgoing call
                              }
                break;
            }

            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    };

}
```

You will need to register an PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE for receiving only

incoming call inside BroadcastReceiver.